# &allow-other-keys , What does it do? - Common Lisp

Tags: macros, key, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I'm interested in knowing what `&allow-other-keys` is supposed to do. I'm getting shockingly few references to it and no real definitions when I consult all documentation I can get my hands on. Best I can figure out is that it's effectively an error handling bit of code that you can put after &key to suppress the checking of key arguments when the macro is being called. For reference, this is where I found it:

```
(defmacro macro-name ((passed-variable
                       &rest open-args
                       &key &allow-other-keys)
                      &body body)
  ...)
```

Comment: A quick example: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/functions.html#allow-other-keys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`&allow-other-keys`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_dada.htm) is well documented: it suppresses Keyword Argument Checking.

In your example, it makes `(macro-name (foo :bar 1) ...)` an acceptable invocation of `macro-name`.

Comment: Thanks for that. Can't for the life of me figure out why I wasn't able to find that particular page. Must have missed it. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Although I think sds's answer is the right one, it's worth perhaps giving an example what is probably the canonical use-case for `&allow-other-keys`:

```
(defun open-unsigned-byte (f &rest kws &key &allow-other-keys)
  (apply #'open f :element-type 'unsigned-byte kws))
```

This function wants to let `open` have whatever keyword arguments it takes, possibly including non-standard ones, but wants to make sure that the element-type is `unsigned-byte`, and that all the additional arguments passed to `open` *are* keyword arguments.  This works because in the case of duplicated keyword arguments (which are legal) the leftmost one wins.